# how to send xml over HTTP Request using telnet in java

Tags: java, httprequest, telnet, serversocket

I am trying to send an HTML POST request over telnet in Java, I have some XML content which I have to send. But when I try to achieve in java, i am getting "Connection Reset" error. But the same when I do it over putty(unix), I am getting the response xml correctly.

Java Program I used : (Resulting in Connection Reset error)

```
public class Telnet {public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

       Socket socket = new Socket("hostname", 10020);
       String xmled = "<?xml version=1.0?><methodCall><methodName>GetVoucherDetails</methodName><params><param><value><struct><member><name>serialNumber</name><value><string>1038291567</string></value></member><member><name>networkOperatorId</name><value><string>vno2</string></value></member></struct></value></param></params></methodCall>"; 
       System.out.println("Params: " + xmled);

        try {
            Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");
            out.write("POST /someContext HTTP/1.1\r\n");
            out.write("Accept: text/xml\r\n"); 
            out.write("Connection: close\r\n"); 
            out.write("Content-Length: 489\r\n"); 
            out.write("Content-Type: text/xml\r\n"); 
            out.write("Host: ws2258:10010\r\n"); 
            out.write("User-Agent: ADM/2.4/6.2\r\n"); 
            out.write("Authorization: Basic cHBtc3VzZXI6dnNfJF9wcG11NWVy\r\n");
            out.write(xmled);  
            out.write("\r\n");  
            out.flush();

            InputStream inputstream = socket.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader inputstreamreader = new InputStreamReader(inputstream);
            BufferedReader bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(inputstreamreader);

            String string = null;
            string = bufferedreader.readLine();
            System.out.println(string);
            while ((string = bufferedreader.readLine()) != null) {
               System.out.println("Received " + string);
            }

       } catch(Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       } finally {
         socket.close(); 
       }
 }
```

}

Please suggest me something, I am new to socket programming.

Comment: I don't test your code, but you need 2 `\r\n` between HTTP header and body (`xmled`)

Comment: The code already has \r\n between header and body.. I am getting this 500 timed out error for this program.

Comment: "Connection reset" is a typical error when you try to write to a socket that has been closed by the remote end. Check the server logs to see what happened on the server.

Comment: What @LiuYan刘研 means is that you need an _extra_ `"\r\n"` pair between the header and the body, i.e. between the `"Authorization"` header and `xlmed`.

Answer (score 0):

In your Socket constructor, did you mean to put port 10020?  HTTP implies port 80 unless your web server is listening on port 10020.

Answer (score 0):

I finally have found the solution for this problem. The fix was quiet simple at the end. We had to send the entire XML content in one single line rather then putting into multiple lines.

Comment: You should probably explain this better. You already send the entire XML content in one single line in the code that you show in the question. What have you changed with respect to that?